# Change label of cell values but keep their colouring

Tags: r, datatable, dt

I am using the `DT` package to colour a frequency table consisting of numeric cell values (`df_numbered`, see below).

```
library(DT)
df_numbered <- data.frame(cat1 = 1:3,
                          cat2 = 4:6,
                          cat3 = 7:9)
```

However, I would like to substitute the displayed numeric value for a character label (e.g. the name of the category found in `df_labeled`).

```
df_labeled <- data.frame(cat1 = letters[1:3],
                         cat2 = letters[4:6], 
                         cat3 = letters[7:9])
```

To colour the table I follow these instructions: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html.

```
brks <- quantile(df_numbered, probs = seq(.05, .95, .05), na.rm = TRUE)
clrs <- round(seq(255, 40, length.out = length(brks) + 1), 0) %>%
{paste0("rgb(255,", ., ",", ., ")")}
datatable(df_numbered) %>% 
          formatStyle(names(df_numbered), 
          backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
```

This works fine for `df_numbered`. Now I would like to relabel the displayed cell values with their corresponding label from `df_labeled`.

I tried to save the datatable object and replace the data, but I lose the colouring in the process.

```
dt <- datatable(df_numbered) %>%
                formatStyle(names(df_numbered), 
                backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
dt$x$data <- df_labeled
```

My question is, how do I keep the colouring but change the displayed cell value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by binding the two dataframes:

```
df_numbered <- data.frame(c1 = 1:3,
                          c2 = 4:6,
                          c3 = 7:9)
df_labeled <- data.frame(cat1 = letters[1:3],
                         cat2 = letters[4:6], 
                         cat3 = letters[7:9])
df <- cbind(df_labeled, df_numbered)
```

Then you can format in this way:

```
formatStyle(names(df_labeled), valueColumns = names(df_numbered),  
            backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
```

But you don't want the `df_numbered` columns, so hide them:

```
datatable(df, 
          options = list(
            columnDefs = list(
              list(visible = FALSE, targets = 4:6)
            )
          )) %>% 
  formatStyle(names(df_labeled), valueColumns = names(df_numbered),  
              backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!